# Circles of different radius based on other values in d3

Tags: node.js, d3.js, networking, graph

I am trying to create nodes whose radius depend on the amount value in the link array. The data structure is as shown below:

```
{  "nodes": [{"id": "site01", "x": 317.5, "y": 282.5},
{"id": "site02", "x": 112, "y": 47},
{"id": "site03", "x": 69.5,"y": 287},
{"id": "site04", "x": 424.5, "y": 99.5},
],
"links": [
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site04", "amount": 10},
{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site02", "amount": 120},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site03", "amount": 50},
{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site02", "amount": 80}]
}
```

The radius must be proportional to the total amount. For example, site01 must be of radius 60 while site02, 200. I've tried few codes but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var nodeRadius = {};
        data.links.forEach(function (n){
            nodeRadius[n.id] = n;
        });

nodes.attr("r", function (d) {return nodeRadius[d.node01].amount;})
```

Please suggest a working code.

Comment: you'll have to transform your data into the one that'd contain such info before binding it to the selection

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Do you suggest me to change the data in the actual file?

Comment: no not in file, just have function that takes your file data and transforms into more convenient format for working in d3 (so in your case explicitly store the connection count in each site directly), and then just call it before invoking data binding function; ie `selection.data(transformerFunction(actualDataFromFile))`